# Pygame, when I press a key a surface blits and when I repress it it dissapears. Why such a delay making the surface disappear?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have a surface that enters a blit stack(a stack that has items to blit to the screen) when I press a key. When I repress that key it is taken off the blit stack and disappears from the display. But whenever and only whenever I try to take it off there's a little delay in it disappearing from the pygame.display. I switched from pygame.display.update() to pygame.display.flip() and it's a bit faster but are there any other tricks to speeding this up? I'm on a slow computer btw.

Comment: We need to see the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How about we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .convert() when your loading images if you're using external images but it would help to see some code https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert